# total sum is not working on angular using forEach

Tags: angular, typescript, foreach, sum, angular8

I am trying to get total sum from the api and my code is
.ts file

```
getProducts() {
this.service.getcustomize().subscribe((res) => {
  this.Products = res['result']
})
  }
  get cartTotal() {
    let total = 0;
    this.Products.forEach((data, index) => {
      total += data['price'];
    });
    return total;
  }
```

my html file is

```
 <h5 class="text-right">Total:
      <span class="ml-1 font-weight-bold text-danger">{{ cartTotal | currency }}</span>
    </h5>
```

but i am getting

```
$12,001,200.00
```

my api list is

```
 {success: true, result: [,…]}
    result: [,…]
    0: {productId: 197, 
    price: "1200"
    createdAt: "2020-05-04T07:45:41.000Z"
    updatedAt: "2020-05-04T07:45:41.000Z"
    1: {productId: 198, 
    price: "1200"
    createdAt: "2020-05-04T07:45:41.000Z"
    updatedAt: "2020-05-04T07:45:41.000Z"
    }
```

I should get $2400 but i am getting $12,001,200.00

Answer (score 1):

because by using `+` with string you are not adding but concatinating strings

use this

```
total += parseFloat(data['price']);
```

check this to understand the difference

```js
 var a = "123"
 var b = "567"
 
 console.log(a+b)
 console.log(parseFloat(a)+parseFloat(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

because the price is a string you need to convert it to a number.
Simply apply `parseFloat` to it.

```js
total += parseFloat(`${data['price']}`);
```

a wrapper with quotes converts all types to a string, so if price becomes a number the `parseFloat` won't fail.